# Is it possible to use group_by in a function for more than one variable?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, group-by

I created a function that aggregates the numeric values in a dataset, and I use a group_by() function to group the data first. Below is an example of what the code I wrote looks like. Is there a way I can group_by() more than one variable without having to create another input for the function?

`agg <- function(data, group){ aggdata <- data %>% group_by({{group}}) %>% select_if(function(col) !is.numeric(col) & !is.integer(col)) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm = TRUE)                         return(aggdata)`

Comment: I'll repeat my last comment to you: **For this new question about `dplyr`, it would help to have a reproducible example. Pick a built-in data set (mtcars is a popular choice) and show exactly how you would want to use your function. foo(mtcars, group = c("cyl", "am"), var = c("mpg", "hp")) would be a pretty easy function to write...** You haven't suggested a sample data set. You haven't shown an example of how you would like to call the function. And you seem to have some syntax and other issues with your code... I think you're missing at least one `}` and `col` is never defined.

Comment: There seems to be some things missing from this function, and we cant recreate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has (at least) a misplaced curly brace, and it's a bit difficult to see what you're trying to accomplish without a reproducible example and desired result.

It is possible to pass a vector of variable names to `group_by()`. For example, the following produces the same result as `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear)`:

```
my_groups <- c("cyl", "gear")
mtcars %>% group_by(!!!syms(my_groups))
```

Maybe you could use this syntax within your function definition.